# Send data from windows mobile to server

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

Hello frnds
I have windows mobile application, that retrieves location info. Now i want to send  this data  to asp.net running on localhost. How to proceed?
Please. I tried sending like below.

```
    string url = "http://localhost/testwebsite/default.aspx?field1=name";
    private void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString()); }
    }
```

But nothing happpens.

Also i don't understand how to retrieve the sent values from windows mobile client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done it via a webservice. the mobile client sends data , and web service handles the data and sends to the server. 
First create a webservice , then add web refernce of the service to your project from where your going to send data. 
in my case i gave the refrence name as transferData1
then you have to import it in your project

```
using Client.transferData1;
```

then you can call the methods from webservice as give below

```
  private void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        transferData1.Service ser = new transferData1.Service();
        transferData1.SQLInsertBase ins = new transferData1.SQLInsertBase();
        ins = ser.GetSQLInsertCourse("359807016319431", "12.22", "44.54","6/20/2011","10:55");

        /*out1.Service ser = new out1.Service();
        out1.SQLInsertBase ins = new out1.SQLInsertBase();
        ins = ser.GetSQLInsertCourse("8", "91.45", "56.22");*/
        if (ins.SQLInsertOK == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Coordinates transfered sucessfully!!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ins.SQLInsertError);
        }

    }
```

the webservice code i have given in my other question . please read it 
[Webservice code to handle data and insert into db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665884/web-service-to-insert-values-into-sql-database/8183970#8183970)

Answer (score 0):

Your are not asking for any response in your code:

```
  try {
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
    // Statuscode = 200 for OK (look for HTTP-Status Codes)
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
```

To retreive the message on the server, you have to write at least a small Web- / Service-Application, which listens on the specified address for incoming requests.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. how to do that on server side. Please help

Comment: I tried calling the webService from emulator, but am getting the following error "Unable to connect Remote Server"

Comment: My Client code                                                                try
            {
                Myservice.Service loc = new Myservice.Service();
                label1.Text = loc.LocationInfo("12");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }                                                                    My webservice code [WebMethod]
    public string LocationInfo(String lat) {
        return lat;
    }